# Draw rectangle in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to draw a rectangle in OpenCV by using this function:

```
rectangle(Mat& img, Rect rec, const Scalar& color, int thickness=1, int lineType=8, int shift=0 )
```

But when I use it I am facing some errors. My question is: can anyone explain the function with an example? I found some examples but with another function:

```
rectangle(Mat& img, Point pt1, Point pt2, const Scalar& color, int thickness=1, int lineType=8, int shift=0)
```

This example on the second function:

```
rectangle(image, pt2, pt1, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0);
```

This function I understand, but with the first function I'm facing a problem in parameter `Rect`. I don't know how I can deadlier it?

Answer (score 25):

The `cv::rectangle` function that accepts two `cv::Point`'s takes both the top left and the bottom right corner of a rectangle (pt1 and pt2 respectively in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=rectangle#rectangle)).  If that rectangle is used with the `cv::rectangle` function that accepts a `cv::Rect`, then you will get the same result.

```
// just some valid rectangle arguments
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int width = 10;
int height = 20;
// our rectangle...
cv::Rect rect(x, y, width, height);
// and its top left corner...
cv::Point pt1(x, y);
// and its bottom right corner.
cv::Point pt2(x + width, y + height);
// These two calls...
cv::rectangle(img, pt1, pt2, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0));
// essentially do the same thing
cv::rectangle(img, rect, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0))
```

Comment: I did as you gave me the example but the function didn't draw the rectangle on the image but was drawn at the corner. do you want me to join my code to take a look

Comment: As it stands above, the top left corner of the rectangle is the top left corner of the image.  Maybe you can somehow post the image you are using or show what's going wrong?

Comment: /* Global variables */
CascadeClassifier pedestrians_cascade;
Mat image1;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int w = 10;
int h = 20;

int main( )
{
 // Load Face cascade (.xml file)
 pedestrians_cascade = CascadeClassifier("hogcascade_pedestrians.xml");
    
 // Read an images
    image5 = imread("ped5.jpg");
 Rect rect(x,y,w,h);
 std::vector<Rect> faces1;
    pedestrians_cascade.detectMultiScale( image1, faces1, 1.1, 2, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
 rectangle(image1, rect, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0));
 imshow( "Window1", image1);
 waitKey(0);                   
    return 0;
}

Comment: Yeah, it looks fine, but those values for your rectangle are probably not what you want.  Try playing around with the values for x, y, width, and height.

Comment: how I can get the values that I want

Comment: I guess something like `rectangle(image1, faces1[0], cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0));` would plot the first detection from `pedestrians_cascade` if there were any detections.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a simple example of drawing a pre-defined rectangle on an image

```
using namespace cv;

int main(){
Mat img=imread("myImage.jpg");

Rect r=Rect(10,20,40,60);
//create a Rect with top-left vertex at (10,20), of width 40 and height 60 pixels.

rectangle(img,r,Scalar(255,0,0),1,8,0);
//draw the rect defined by r with line thickness 1 and Blue color

imwrite("myImageWithRect.jpg",img);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for example, but how can I draw rectangle on an image.

Comment: I have image and I want to draw a rectangle on it by that function

Comment: this is an example to demonstrate the Rect(x,y,w,h) object. rectangle() function is used to draw the Rect on the image. If you already have an image, then you use the rectangle() call as demonstrated above to draw a rectangle on it

Comment: can you please take a look on my own code which is above your post.