# How to build cv::Mat from coloured rectangles

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, rect

My goal is to create yield maps using OpenCV. These yield maps need to be built with coloured rectangles to indicate yield. An example of a Mat built by rectangles [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwqEu.png).

So is it possible to create a cv::Mat with coloured rectangles? The amount of rectangles isn't constant, thus changes with every use.

To make the question clear: if I have 4 boxes (2x2 grid) I want to automatically make a Mat which is as big as the 4 boxes. If I have 16 boxes (4x4 grid) I want to make a Mat which is as big as the 16 boxes.

I couldn't find a way to make it work, so I hope somebody here knows if it is possible.

If somebody can help me that would be great, if it is not possible alternatives are also welcome! Thanks

Some info:

- OpenCV version:4.5.3
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Language: C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV has `cv::hconcat` and `cv::vconcat`. Use them like numpy's hstack/vstack.

make sure your parts have the same type (and number of channels).

[The documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaf9771c991763233866bf76b5b5d1776f) has a code example.

```cpp
cv::Mat matArray[] = { cv::Mat(4, 1, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(1)),
                       cv::Mat(4, 1, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(2)),
                       cv::Mat(4, 1, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(3)),};
cv::Mat out;
cv::hconcat( matArray, 3, out );
//out:
//[1, 2, 3;
// 1, 2, 3;
// 1, 2, 3;
// 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Okay, this is something I could work with, I think. I'll try it out. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create rectangle with OpenCV function.

[Basic Geometric Drawing OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d96/tutorial_basic_geometric_drawing.html)

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int width = 10;
int height = 20;
// our rectangle...
cv::Rect rect(x, y, width, height);
// and its top left corner...
cv::Point pt1(x, y);
// and its bottom right corner.
cv::Point pt2(x + width, y + height);
// These two calls...
cv::rectangle(img, pt1, pt2, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0));
// essentially do the same thing
cv::rectangle(img, rect, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0))
```

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40120433/draw-rectangle-in-opencv)

Comment: Yeah this makes one rectangle, this I know. But I want to make a Picture (cv::Mat) which consists of multiple rectangles, not just one. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: so just draw more of them? I'm inclined to flag this question as a duplicate. you need to give your question more detail.

Comment: My question is how build a Mat purely on the rectangles, without a starting image. For example:  if I have 4 boxes (2x2 grid) I want to automatically make a Mat which is as big as the 4 boxes. If I have 16 boxes (4x4 grid) I want to make a Mat which is as big as the 16 boxes. And if it is even possible

Comment: I understand from your question that you want draw a  rectangle but not more.